# Problems with react to translate words using google translate api

Tags: reactjs, axios, rapidapi

I am trying to create a translation page where you type the word and it should translate to the language you chose in the dropdown. Using React and axios and the API from Rapid API.

I keep getting error like 401, 429 I know what the errors are but don't know how to fix it. Could it be from the website [Rapid API][1] that gives me a bad API?

````
import axios from "axios"

// de-structure language and text props
const Convert = ({ language, text }) => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const translate = async () => {
      const translation = await axios.post(
        "https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2",
        {},
        {
          params: {
            q: text,
            target: language.value,
            key: "cd4662825bmshfb23e36cc668d7fp111f42jsn736f6cc3a9aa",
          },
        }
      )

      setResults(translation.data.data.translations[0].translatedText)
    }

    translate()
  }, [language, text])
console.log(results);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{results}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Convert ```


  [1]: https://rapidapi.com/googlecloud/api/google-translate1?endpoint=apiendpoint_a5764907-04b6-4d61-869b-79dc5325c739
````

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 different APIs here... You are talking about the [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com) API but in the code you are using the [MyMemory](https://mymemory.translated.net/) API.

So, regarding to your code and the [MyMemory API specification](https://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php), I see a couple errors in your code:

1. You are calling the */status* endpoint, which checks the status of a TM import. I think this is not the endpoint you want to call. Instead, you have to make the request to the */get* endpoint: https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get.
2. Also the request should be a **get**, not a **post** (just replace `axios.post` with `axios.get`).
3. The "q" and "key" params are correct, BUT in the documentation it says that you have to send a "langpair" param, not a "target".

With those changes the code should go fine. I've tried it and it works.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I change the API now to the rapid one. and from the website, I am using Post translate

Comment: Oh ok!! I've just tried the new code and it seems that the API key is invalid. Maybe it's misspelled or the key was revoked or something? I would suggest that you generate another API key and try, if you can

Comment: did you use the exact code or you changed some things in it? it's just that i am trying to figure out what is going on and i have no clue what to do now. i am on that web side but i keep getting the same KEY

Comment: Yes, I used that same code with the same API key. And the exact error message I'm getting is "Invalid API key. Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys for more info."

Comment: Thanks, man but I made another key and I still get the 401 code error

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import qs from "qs"

// de-structure language and text props
const Convert = ({ language, text }) => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    const translate = async () => {
      const translation = await axios.post(
        "https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2",
        qs.stringify({
          q: text,
          target: language.value
        }),
        {
          headers: {
            'x-rapidapi-key': 'cd4662825bmshfb23e36cc668d7fp111f42jsn736f6cc3a9aa',
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com'
          }
        }
      )

      setResults(translation.data.data.translations[0].translatedText)
    }

    translate()
  }, [])
  console.log(results);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{results}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Convert
```

If you get a **403 Forbidden** error then it's possibly because you're not subscribed to the API. To fix this, just go to https://rapidapi.com/googlecloud/api/google-translate1 and click on the "Subscribe to Test" button. Then select the free plan and you will be ready to go.

Comment: Hey, ok i made a new API : ed43677c76msh78d9e1861978f2ap14e561jsn05c9e080cf5c
and i am not getting the errors anymore, but i am not getting anywords translated

thank you

Comment: this is the whole code i am getting from rapid API site but it's not exactly react

Comment: Here is the link with code from rapid API, but it is not react https://codeshare.io/GbVkMO

Comment: I used this guy's walkthrough https://ncoughlin.com/posts/react-translate-widget/#making-the-api-request

Comment: That code you shared is almost perfect. The only thing you have to do to make it work is "stringify" the data object. To do this, just import the "qs" library and apply the "stringify" method over the data object. Take a look at my code and notice what I'm talking about

Comment: I did look at your code and i tried and i don't have that errors anymore with the API, but my issue now is to output the translation from my input. but i think i need to change that in the translate file, it's another one besides this one. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points that can definitely solve this issue.

- If you're using RapidAPI then `x-rapidapi-key` is your API key. So instead of mentioning `key` in params, you can pass `x-rapidapi-key` inside the headers.
- The possible reason for the 403 code is that you're not subscribed to that particular API. Make sure to double-check that.
- 429 status code indicates so many request in the give amount of time. I have checked, the rate limit is 5 request per second for [Google Translate API](https://rapidapi.com/googlecloud/api/google-translate1/pricing).
- You can use the code snippet that RapidAPI provides in order to avoid any kind of unwanted errors.